# Have Leaflet panTo not center

Tags: leaflet

I have a trail on a map that the user can "follow" by mousing over a graph (time and speed). If the user zooms in a lot, part of the trail may not be visible. When the user wants to see the part of the trail that is not showing I use the panTo method...

The panTo method of leaflet is currently also **centering**. I don't want to center, I want the map to move *just enough* to show a point. (The problem with panTo is it causes excessive map scrolling and a harsh user experience.)

I have tried changing the bounds, but that has an (unwanted) side affect of sometimes zooming out.

Any way I can do a "minimal" panTo?

---

This is a (working but unpolished) solution; map is our own map wrapper utility class, lmap is a leaflet map object in typescript, and toxy() is a method to convert lat/longs to x/y values.

```
 if (!this.lmap.getBounds().contains(latlng)) {
    let target = this.map.toxy(latlng);

    let nw = this.map.toxy(this.lmap.getBounds().getNorthWest());
    let se = this.map.toxy(this.lmap.getBounds().getSouthEast());
    let x = 0, y = 0;

    let margin = 75;
    if (target.y < nw.y)
       y = (-1 * (nw.y - target.y)) - margin;
    else if (target.y > se.y)
       y = (target.y - se.y) + margin;

    if (target.x < nw.x)
       x = (-1 * (nw.x - target.x)) - margin;
    else if (target.x > se.x)
       x = (target.x - se.x) + margin;

    this.lmap.panBy(new L.Point(x, y));
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, fetch the bounds of the map (measured in pixels from the CRS origin) with [`map.getPixelBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-getpixelbounds). Then, use [`map.project(latlng, map.getZoom())`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-project) to get the coordinates (in pixels from the CRS origin) of the point you're interested.

If you're confused about this "pixels from the CRS origin" thing, read the "Pixel Origin" section at http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html .

Once you have these pixel coordinates, it should be a simple matter of checking whether the point is inside the viewport, and if not, how far away on each direction it is.

Comment: Once you know how many pixels away the point is, you can use `map.panBy()` to pan it into view.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using panBy(), much less map-scrolling so a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jcollin6/b131tobj/2/

Should give you what you want

```
function clamp(n,lower,upper) {
  return Math.max(lower, Math.min(upper, n));
}
//Shamelessly stolen from https://gist.github.com/dwtkns/d5b9b60285b8b0067c53
function getNearestPointInPerimeter(l,t,w,h,x,y) {
  var r = l+w,
      b = t+h;

  var x = clamp(x,l,r),
      y = clamp(y,t,b);

  var dl = Math.abs(x-l),
      dr = Math.abs(x-r),
      dt = Math.abs(y-t),
      db = Math.abs(y-b);

  var m = Math.min(dl,dr,dt,db);

  return (m===dt) ? {x: x, y: t} :
         (m===db) ? {x: x, y: b} :
         (m===dl) ? {x: l, y: y} : {x: r, y: y};
}

L.ExtendedMap = L.Map.extend({
  panInside: function (latlng, pad, options) {
    var padding = pad ? pad : 0;
    var pixelBounds = this.getPixelBounds();
    var center = this.getCenter();
    var pixelCenter = this.project(center);
    var pixelPoint = this.project(latlng);
    var sw = pixelBounds.getBottomLeft();
    var ne = pixelBounds.getTopRight();
    var topLeftPoint = L.point(sw.x + padding, ne.y + padding);
    var bottomRightPoint = L.point( ne.x - padding, sw.y - padding);
    var paddedBounds = L.bounds(topLeftPoint, bottomRightPoint);

    if (!paddedBounds.contains(pixelPoint)) {
      this._enforcingBounds = true;

      var nearestPoint = getNearestPointInPerimeter(
        sw.x + padding, 
        ne.y + padding, 
        ne.x - sw.x - padding * 2, 
        sw.y - ne.y - padding * 2, 
        pixelPoint.x, 
        pixelPoint.y
      );
      var nearestPixelPoint = L.point(nearestPoint.x,nearestPoint.y)
      var diffPixelPoint = nearestPixelPoint.subtract(pixelPoint);
      var newPixelCenter = pixelCenter.subtract(diffPixelPoint);
      var newCenter = this.unproject(newPixelCenter);
      if (!center.equals(newCenter)) {
        this.panTo(newCenter, options);
      }
      this._enforcingBounds = false;
    }
    return this;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this way

```
map.panTo([lat, lng]);
map.setZoom(Zoom);
```